# http://www.sub1.domain.co.uk to https://sub1.domain.co.uk

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following to redirect http to https and www to non www.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# force non-www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

But it doesn't catch http://www.sub1.domain.co.uk, or https://www.sub1.domain.co.uk, and redirect to https://sub1.domain.co.uk, what would I need to add to do this?

Comment: Your code should already do this if the `www.sub1` subdomain resolves to the same place (or a subdirectory and there are no other `.htaccess` files).

Comment: It doesn't, I've updated the htaccess to show the complete file, the htaccess is in a subdirectory where the domain is being served from, there is an htaccess in the parent directory but that it a different sub domain so wont get touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've updated the htaccess to show the complete file

Your canonical redirects should go *before* your front controller (internal rewrites). As a general rule, redirects should always go before rewrites in `.htaccess`.

By placing these redirects *after* the front controller they are never executed since the preceding rewrite handles all requests.

Your redirects could also be optimised:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force non-www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

By having your canonical www redirect first you avoid a secondary redirect when accessing the `www` subdomain. No need to have captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* if they are not being used. You were missing the `301` status from the HTTPS redirect. The `QSA` and `NC` flags were superfluous on the www redirect.

You only need to include the `RewriteEngine` directive once, preferably at the top of the file.